# Show the triple integral given is equivalent to $\frac{15\pi}{16}$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, spherical-coordinates

Evaluate $$\iiint_E\;z \, dV$$
where E is enclosed between the spheres $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$`and`$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 4$ in the first octant.

I'll be honest. My first attempt didn't worked very well. My answer showed for my first attempt was 7pi/12 because the integral I set up was like this:

$$\iiint _E\;z\;dV\\
1\leq \rho\leq 2\\
0\leq\theta\leq \frac{1}{2}\pi\\
0\leq\phi\leq \frac{1}{2}\pi$$

Which transforms the integral into

$$\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}\pi}\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}\pi}\int_{1}^{2}(\rho)^2 cos\phi\sin\phi\ d\rho\; d\theta \;d\phi\\$$

This problem was taken from Stewart Calculus 6th Edition. Like I said, I tried to solve this problem on my own and got an answer of $$\frac {7}{12}\pi$$

but when I browsed the answers section, it says its answer was $$\frac {15}{16}\pi$$

Did I do something wrong in my computation?

Comment: At a glance, your integrand is wrong: informally speaking, when you use spherical coordinates, you have $$z\, dV = \rho \cos \phi \cdot \rho^2 \sin \phi\, d\rho\, d\theta\, d\phi$$ or something like that. I don't have time to check this, though, so I leave that to you. (If it works, let me know and I'll turn this comment into an actual answer.)

Comment: The Problem was edited. Actually, I just misplaced the extra "rho" variable. The answer was still the same.

Comment: @Jem Celespara You seem to have forgotten a factor $\rho$ in the integrand. Please, see my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**. Observe that the converted integral is rather
$$
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\!\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\!\int_{1}^{2}\rho\cos\phi \:\rho^2\sin\phi\ d\rho\; d\theta \;d\phi=\int_{1}^{2}\rho^3d\rho\times \int_{0}^{\pi/2}d\theta\times \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin(2\phi)}2 d\phi=\frac{15}{16}\pi
$$ as announced.

Comment: Thank you! I realized that I was actually careless all along. I forgot the additiontal "rho" variable. Which is why I got wrong all along.